# SAM template for an EventBridge that triggers SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I have an EventBridge that receives events and want to publish it to SQS that triggers Lambdafunction using sam template

putting events on EventBridge is ok, but the SQS doesn't have been trigger by the EventBridge

do I have any errors in the following `yaml`

```yaml
eventSqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  eventSynchronizer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: build/eventSynchronizer
      Handler: eventSynchronizer.Handler      
      Events:
        MySQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn
            BatchSize: 10

  eventEventRule: 
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:      
      EventPattern: 
        account: 
          - !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}'
        source:
          - "microserviceName"
        DetailType:
          - "event Created"
          - "event Updated"
          - "event Deleted"
      Targets: 
        - Arn: !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn
          Id: "SQSqueue"

  EventBridgeToToSqsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: events.amazonaws.com
          Action: SQS:SendMessage
          Resource:  !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn          
      Queues:
        - Ref: eventSqsQueue
```

Answer (score 3):

`DetailType` should be `detail-type` and with some delete to extra written code

Here is the final solution

````yaml
eventSqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  eventSynchronizer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: build/eventSynchronizer
      Handler: eventSynchronizer.Handler
      # ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 1      
      Events:
        MySQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn
            BatchSize: 10

  eventEventRule: 
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: "eventEventRule"
      EventPattern:       
        source:
          - "microserviceName"
        detail-type:
          - "event Created"
          - "event Updated"
          - "event Deleted"
      Targets: 
        - Arn: !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn
          Id: "SQSqueue"

  EventBridgeToToSqsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: events.amazonaws.com
          Action: SQS:SendMessage
          Resource:  !GetAtt eventSqsQueue.Arn          
      Queues:
        - Ref: eventSqsQueue
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your template for errors,  use

`$ sam validate`

More info here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-validate.html